# Pytest test discovery in subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pytest, pytest-selenium

Hi I have the following project architecture, I am using selenium with pytest

[image]

- From the terminal, when I am at the root folder, I can not run one
  the tests inside the folder "\tests"
- As far as you know Pytest should be able to discover all tests in the
  subfolders or I am getting this wrong?

**The command I am using is:**
(venv) C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\UI_Selenium_Framework> pytest test_logib_logout.py
I am getting ERROR: file not found: test_login_logout.py

**And when I run**
(venv) C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\UI_Selenium_Framework> pytest
pytest discovers all tests inside "\tests" and run it successfully

Answer (score 0):

You should run `pytest tests\test_login_logout.py`. You have to specify the complete path from the current working directory, which is `C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\UI_Selenium_Framework` in your case.

Note that you can also use Python's unittest module: `python3 -m unittest discover tests`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to open the terminal in the folder where the pytest files are saved and run the command.

In your case the command should look like this:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\UI_Selenium_Framework\tests> pytest test_logib_logout.py
```

You can also generate an html report (if you have `pytest-html` plugin installed) by running the command `pytest test_logib_logout.py --html=testreport.html`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using '-k'

```
(venv) C:\Users\Mike\PycharmProjects\UI_Selenium_Framework> pytest -k test_login_logout.py
```